# Which area of Maths should I pursue?

Tags: elliptic-curves, number-theory

I would like to know which area of Mathematics would be most beneficial to cryptography. Surely Algebraic Number Theory and maybe to a lesser extend, Elliptic Curves, are closely linked to Cryptography; but are there more fields that would apply neatly to Cryptography?

What topics would you recommend to a Maths graduate who is looking for a career in Cryptography?

(I wanted to tag this as a "soft-question" as they do in math.stackexchange)

Comment: Discrete mathematics and group theory can be a start. You could also find [this](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/8443/5231) (somewhat different) question useful. A soft question (one that does not admit a definite answer) is a tad against the policy (see [this section](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Abstract Algebra
2. Number theory
3. Statistics
4. Computer/Network security (so you can see the application)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to me a situation of the tail wagging the dog. Personally I have always found something I want to do such as zero knowledge proofs, faster primality testing, shorter signatures and then learned the relevant maths - bilinear pairings, elementary number theory and elliptic curves respectively.
Cryptography is now a big subject and you can't hope to know enough maths to be comfortable in all areas - for instance the maths needed for differential/linear cryptanalysis is completely separate from the maths for asymmetric cryptography.

If you really are a maths graduate, what would a career in cryptography look like? Who would be your supervisor? Which university? Similar constraints are relevant in a commercial setting too.

Answer (score 1):

I would add **Probabilities Theory** and **Linear Algebra** as it turns to become the de facto source for intractable problems for the unreal yet fully homomorphic encryption schemes