# Cryptography math requirements

Tags: algorithm-design

I know that most of the math related to cryptography is number theory/abstract algebra/probability, but I was wondering if there are some algorithms that make use of other fields of math like real/complex analysis, differential equations or linear algebra?
Also, what is highest level of mathematics required for cryptography?

Comment: `Also, what is highest level` There is no limit, eg. because crypto is continously evolving.

Comment: Related: [What is the lowest level of mathematics required in order to understand how encryption algorithms work?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/10467/what-is-the-lowest-level-of-mathematics-required-in-order-to-understand-how-encr)

Comment: *"I know that most of the math related to cryptography is number theory/abstract algebra"* Nope, it's mostly probability.

Comment: There are plenty of linear algebra concepts, and it can be quite useful. Vector spaces show up everywhere when dealing with finite fields, and finite fields are all over crypto.

Comment: @SAIPeregrinus Or when dealing with lattices... I wonder if this question might not be primarily opinion based. It really depends on the crypto you want to do. Whatever you do in crypto, you'll always benefit from a good basis in math, and analysis is a very rigorous branch of math, thus a good thing to learn.  But I'd say the most "complex" pieces of crypto I've seen so far are all dealing with strange algebraic constructs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It would be hard to find a category of mathematics not related in some way to cryptography, here is a list of [applied mathematics by subject area](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2556/real-world-applications-of-mathematics-by-arxiv-subject-area). Even very abstract mathematics could be future cryptographic tools waiting to happen:

"A large part of mathematics which becomes useful developed with absolutely no desire to be useful, and in a situation where nobody could possibly know in what area it would become useful; and there were no general indications that it ever would be so. "