# Is being cryptanalyst synonymous with being a code breaker?

Tags: cryptanalysis

I have been recently considering becoming a cryptanalyst. I have moderate background in mathematics, but I am not sure if that is the case with breaking codes and cryptanalysis is just like in the movies. I have passion for puzzles in many forms and brain teasers, finding patterns etc. I have seen that there are contests with brain teasers that agencies such as GCHQ claim to use to screen candidates for code breakers. I don't generally know how do the things look with general code-breaking and I'm asking for some clarification.

**Is being cryptanalyst synonymous with being a code breaker?**

How much maths will I need? What knowledge will I need?

As someone said with maths Olympiads you use theorems as tools that you have to know well and all the tricks that come with them to do something at Olympiad.

Comment: Academic cryptanalysis is very much **not** like in the movies.

Comment: :/ I meant a movie like the imitation game but it's obvious that the times has changed and algorithms have become more complex.

Comment: @SEJPM Reminds me… [Sneakers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sneakers_(1992_film)) was rather nice. (Yeah, I know – #OldPeopleComments)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First up, please note that this Q&A is primarily opinion based. Therefore, I’ll be focusing on the symmetric part and nothing else you’ve mentioned and/or asked for in your question.

> 99% of cryptanalysis are not code breaker.
>    **If you try a PhD in cryptanalysis and expect to break code, you are dreaming**.

In movies such as [Mercury Rising](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120749/), [Imitation Game](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2084970/) or [A Beautiful Mind](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0268978/), you see cryptanalyst (or child) breaking codes just by being exposed to the cipher text.

Academics consider this kind of attacks as weak. We now works something similar to a [Lunchtime attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chosen-ciphertext_attack). We consider the internals of the algorithm to be know by the attacker and the goal is now to find weakness in it. We are not looking for deciphering a single ciphertext.

Attacks that are used on these algorithm are far more complex (have a look at Differential cryptanalysis, Linear Cryptanalysis, Related keys...)

About the maths level, are required: **Probabilities** (a lot!), Finite Fields, Affine Varieties and other tools, all of them are about Bachelor-Graduate level.

### What is the current state of the art?

In symmetric crypto, using the correct algorithm we are already post-quantum. Should you use strong enough algorithm, even the NSA won't be able to read what you are hiding.

In asymmetric crypto, the research is currently being done to get post-quantum assurance. We have things like [New Hope](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/usenixsecurity16/sec16_paper_alkim.pdf).

---

**EDIT:**

As stated at the beginning of my answer, [the question is **off-topic** by definition.](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/do-we-want-literature-recommendations-and-similar-list-subjective-questions) The reason why it still exists and has been locked (by e-sushi♦) for *“Historical significance”*, is that we thereby gain a Q&A for all those newcommers to cryptography (and our site), who are confusing *“fiction”* (read: code breaking in movies) with *“reality”* (read: modern cryptanalysis in the real world). By keeping this Q&A around, we now have a place to point them to… hoping they learn something from it.

Comment: Very useful answer."If you try a PhD in cryptanalysis and expect to break code, you are dreaming." Yeah, that's what I was quite expecting. Nevertheless all this crypto still looks interesting. I was just examining the field.